# Testing TextView line count with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, textview, robolectric, line-count

I'm trying to write `Robolectric` test cases for `line count` in `TextView`, but I always get `1` as a `line count` whatever the length of the text is.
This is the test case I'm writing:

```
@Test
  fun test() {
    launch(TopicInfoTestActivity::class.java).use {
      it.onActivity { activity ->
        val descriptionTextView = getTopicDescriptionTextView(activity)
        assertThat(descriptionTextView?.lineCount).isEqualTo(5)
      }
    }
  }
```

Test result:

```
expected: 5
but was : 1
```

Another Test case:

```
@Test
  fun secondTest() {
    launchTopicActivityIntent().use {
      onView(withId(R.id.topic_description_text_view))
        .check(matches(lineCount(5)))
    }
  }
```

Here I'm using a custom matcher, here is its code:

```
private fun lineCount(lineCount: Int): TypeSafeMatcher<View> {
    return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
      var count = 0
      override fun matchesSafely(item: View): Boolean {
        count = (item as TextView).lineCount
        return item.lineCount == lineCount
      }

      override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("isTextInLines: $lineCount Got: $count")
      }
    }
  }
```

Test result:

```
Expected: isTextInLines: 5 Got: 1
```

Any idea of how to test the line count with `Robolectric`?

Comment: I don´t understand how your expected value is 5 if the lines are defined in a real device, in some devices to show n characters needs 1 line, another 2, and another n lines, so I think that if you don´t use a device, the result always will be 1.

Comment: But in `Robolectric` tests, we don't use a device. Does this mean that testing `line count` with `Robolectric` is impossible? BTW, I have used this qualifier `@Config(qualifiers = "w120dp-h300dp-mdpi")` and got also 1 line although the text is really long and the text size is big.